# relationships with multiple pivot table Eloquent/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 table

```
users
 id
 name

school
 id
 name

user_school
 id
 user_id
 school_id

user_role
 id
 user_role
 role_id
```

We need to find school users list whose have role id is 2

we use belongsToMany but not success

```
public function totalAdmin(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_school', 'school_id','user_id')->where('user_school.status',1)->where('user_school.deleted',0);
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what `user_school.status` actually refers to here, there's no `status` column in any tables you shared (same with `deleted`)

Comment: Side note, to follow naming [standards](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-table-structure) pivot tables should be `school_user` and `role_user`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have relationships:

- User-Role named `roles` (with pivot user_role)
- School-User named `users` (with pivot user_school)

You can do:

```
School::users()->whereHas('roles', function ($q) {
   $q->where('id', 2);
});
```

You can probably transfer it in the relationship as well:

```
public function totalAdmin(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User','user_school','school_id','user_id')
      ->whereHas('roles', function($q) { $q->where('id', 2); });
}
```